# How to alter image captcha title in drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am working on drupal 7 image captcha module.I want to alter or hide image captcha title like 'What is in your code'.How can I do it by without hacking the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and Form API pre_render function. E.g:

```
// Explains pre_render. This is when you create a form; 
function feedbackForm($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['#pre_render'][] = 'feedbackForm_pre_render';

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Ваше имя'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['actions'] = array(
    '#type' => 'actions',
  );

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Отправить'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function feedbackForm_pre_render($element) {
  $element['captcha']['captcha_widgets']['captcha_response']['#title'] = t('Защитный код');
  return $element;
}
```

You can also use hook_form_alter() function:

```
function MY_MODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);

  if($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'feedbackForm_pre_render';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for quick reply.It worked like charm.Just asking how did you get rendered array like $element['captcha']['captcha_widgets']['captcha_response']['#title'].Earlier I tried to use module_load_include for image_captcha.module to change image_captcha_cpatcha().Could it be done on that way?

Comment: @user3094034 I don't think that you need to change the image_captcha.module or its functions for this task.. hook_form_alter is the suitable way to achieve this kind of functionality.. If you didn't understand how did I get a rendered $element array, you can install Devel module and use its dpm function within pre_render function, like dpm($element) in my case. it will show you all elements of $element array in readable format.